# How to solve the equation...

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am solving the equation

$$(x^z-1)(x+y)^z (x+y-1) -x^z(x-1)((x+y)^z-1) = 0$$

(Consider $x$, $y$ and $z$ are all non zeroes)

But there is no way I could find $(x,y,z)$'s such that equality holds...

Need help. Thanks

Comment: You have unbalanced parenthesis that will be very difficult to guess the correct intent.  Have you distributed all the multiplication to see what might cancel?

Comment: Sorry, I missed the last closing parenthesis

Comment: No worries, it makes sense now.  What have you tried with this expression?

Comment: I solved the equation in terms of $x$. but not quite possible.

Comment: You should't say "note that..", instead you should say "consider that..". Because there is solutions for some zero variables. When you say "note that...", this mean you can conclude that, what is not the case.

Comment: ok, noted.. wait Ill edit it

Answer (score 1):

If $x=0$ you have $-1\cdot y^z(y-1)=0\implies y^z(1-y)=0$. Doing $y=0$ and $z\neq0$ you have infinities solutions. In short, the set $\{ (0,0,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3: \ z\neq 0 \}$ gives you solutions to this equation.

You could use similar reasoning with $y=1$ in $y^z(1-y)=0$ to get another infinite set of solutions.

Another set with nonzero solutions is $\{ (1,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3: \ y,z\in\mathbb{R} \}$.

Comment: what if $x, y,$ and $z$ are nonzero.

Comment: $z$ is already nonzero. But of course still there is more solutions. I just showed you some( yet infinite ) of them.

Comment: thanks @integral, what about all $x, y$ and $z$ are nonzeroes? is there one?

Comment: I'll think about.

Comment: I just edited, there is at least one infinite set with nonzero solutions. Anyway, showing some sets of solutions may be a good start, but its not enough if you want a general solution.

Comment: x cannot be 1..

Comment: And why is that?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10826/discussion-between-keneth-adrian-and-integral)

Answer (score 0):

Note the term $(x+y)^z$ appears twice, here is an expansion of rephrasing the equation around it:

$$(x^z-1)(x+y)^z (x+y-1) -x^z(x-1)((x+y)^z-1) = 0$$

$$=(x^z-1)(x+y-1)(x+y)^z-x^z(x-1)(x+y)^z+x^z(x-1)$$

$$=(x+y)^z\left((x^z-1)(x+y-1)-x^z(x-1)\right)+x^z(x-1)$$

$$=(x+y)^z\left(y(x^z-1)-x-1+x^z(x-1)-x^z(x-1)\right)+x^z(x-1)$$

$$=(x+y)^z\left(y(x^z-1)-(x-1)\right)+x^z(x-1)$$

Noting the solution set allowed by $x=1$, now assume $x\ne 1$ and continue:

$$=(x+y)^z\left(y{x^z-1\over x-1}-1\right)+x^z$$

With a little rearrangement (and assuming $x\ne -y$),

$$\left({x\over x+y}\right)^z=1-y{x^z-1\over x-1}$$

$$\implies \left({x\over x+y}\right)^z+y{x^z-1\over x-1}-1=0$$

$$\implies {(x+y)^z-x^z\over (x+y)^z}=y{x^z-1\over x-1}$$

Comment: If $x =1 $ , then $y^z = 0$; so $x \neq 1$ since we consider all nonzeroes $ x,y$ and $z$.

Comment: @KenethAdrian:  I don't think that is necessarily the case, I made one minor mistake which is now corrected; $x=1$ at least has the solution $y=-1$, among others.

Comment: @KenethAdrian:  I have corrected my algebra again, that $2$ wasn't supposed to be there.